Why is my Swiped card not getting displayed again after all the overlapped cards above it gets swipped in android?
So, I have created a Overlapping Cards, for example there are 3 Cards A,B,C one above the other in following shown below in screen. So, Card A is at the top followed by B and C. What I want to do is , When I swipe Left the Card A, it should go below to Card C , now B will be top most Card and when I Swipe Card B to left, it should go to bottom below A and then When I swipe Card C it should go below Card B and then now Card A should be displayed again. In my Card, Cards do get Swapped by They don't displayed again. Below is the Image of how my cards are. Initially the overlapped Cards look like this Initial image and When I swipe all the Cards, it shows me like this How it's looking
Below is the code of my xml layouts, [fragment_tolearn_flashcards.xml]
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/grey1"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorTypes"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/back_icon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/back_icon"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/back_icon"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emptyImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/waste"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/back_icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />
<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/emptyImage"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/emptyCardText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/you_don_t_have_any_cards"
    />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/back_icon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recycle_view" />

</RelativeLayout>

Below is the code of recycle_view.xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:strokeColor="@color/black"
app:strokeWidth="2dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey1"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
app:cardElevation="3dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameSmile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLeft"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageArrowLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowleft" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#e04e4e"
            android:id="@+id/ifyouswipLeft"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageArrowLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/if_you_didn_t_know_swipe_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/swipleft"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#cd2222"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/ifyouswipLeft"
            android:text="@string/swipe_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeRight"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageArrowRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowright" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor=" #32c741"
            android:id="@+id/ifyouswipRight"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageArrowRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/if_you_were_right" />

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#10a40c"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/ifyouswipRight"
            android:text="@string/swipe_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearSmile"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageCardHelper"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_flashcardview"
        android:src="@drawable/emoji" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/word1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/new_design_text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/word2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="@color/new_design_text_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Below is the code of Swipe Left gesture
val itemTouchHelperLeft = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
) {
            override fun onChildDraw(
                c: Canvas,
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                dX: Float,
                dY: Float,
                actionState: Int,
                isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
            ) {
                val itemView = viewHolder.itemView

                // Apply rotation transformation to the card view if needed
                // (you can add rotation logic here if required)
                // itemView.rotation = rotation

                super.onChildDraw(
                    c,
                    recyclerView,
                    viewHolder,
                    dX,
                    dY,
                    actionState,
                    isCurrentlyActive
                )
            }

            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            val swipeCountMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition

                // Get the swiped card
                val swipedCard = adapter.currentList[position]

                // Update the swipe count for this card
                val swipeCount = swipeCountMap[position] ?: 0
                swipeCountMap[position] = swipeCount + 1

                // Remove the swiped card from the list
                val mutableList = adapter.currentList.toMutableList()
                mutableList.removeAt(position)

                // If the card has been swiped more than the number of cards above it
                // Move it to the top of the stack
                if (swipeCount >= position && swipeCount >= adapter.currentList.size - position - 1) {
                    mutableList.add(0, swipedCard) // Insert at index 0 to move to the top
                    swipeCountMap[position] = 0 // Reset swipe count
                } else {
                    // Add the swiped card to the bottom of the list
                    mutableList.add(swipedCard)
                }

                // Update the adapter with the new list
                adapter.submitList(mutableList)
            }
        })
        itemTouchHelperLeft.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerview)

        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = OverlappingLayoutManager(requireContext())

So, How can I display the Cards again as a Stack, as these Cards overlapped one above the other.
I have created a Left gesture code, And Cards do move Left like i want them to but, they don't get displayed again once they are Left swiped.

Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged somewhere?

Nope, I am not calling it somewhere else

Then that might be a good idea :)
